# Do I have to Raise PropertyChanged in the ViewModel if I use EntityFramework?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I want to use MVVM pattern to develop a WPF application, the Model is an entityframework model. since entityframwork Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raises `PropertyChanged` event in each property setter, do I have to raise this event in the viewmodel properties (wrappers of the model properties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for all properties you are binding to in your view (XAML) otherwise they won't know when they are supposed to update.

Therefore, if you are wrapping the model properties in the view model you will need to raise the event.

However, you can bind to the model properties directly:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Property}" />
```

and as these properties implement `INotifyChanged` the UI will get notified and so will update. Therefore you don't need to wrap them at all.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I can't help but think that you have got your terminology a little wrong... the EF layer is the 'model', while your answer is calling the EF entities the 'model'.

Comment: @slugster - Quite possibly. I've not done a lot of work with the EF so my terminology may be a little off. Feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do.

UI components are bound to your properties, and your properties use EF entity objects. So you can catch changes in entity properties, but how the UI should now about the change? Answer: Your view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raises `PropertyChanged` event.